# Assigning command line arguments to variables

Tags: haskell

I need to convert my command line argument chars to Ints. I would like to assign each one to a variable and use them in my function. I have the following:

```
import System.Environment   

getIntArg :: IO Int
getIntArg = fmap (read . head) getArgs

main = do
    n <- getIntArg
    print n
```

However, it doesn't loop through all the arguments only printing one. Also, would I assign each one to a variable to use?

I'm new to FP.

Comment: why `head` ;) (this is why you only get the first)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to map all arguments to `Int`s you should use

```
getIntArgs :: IO [Int]
getIntArgs = fmap (map read) $ getArgs
```

---

or a bit shorter:

```
getIntArgs = map read <$> getArgs
```

---

instead.

This way you can do

```
main = do
    ns <- getIntArgs
    print ns
```

and then get the ones you are interested in with `(!!)` or if you know/expect at least a fixed number of `Int` - arguments with

```
(n1:n2:n3:_) <- getIntArgs
```

but of course you should maybe check the length first - also this will fail if the user decides to input things that cannot get parsed into `Int`s

---

So if you don't want to reinvent the wheel (which might be ok if you want to learn or only need a quick solution) you maybe want to look around and use a existing package - for example [parseargs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parseargs) to do this for you

Comment: Just a small remark: As long as Ubuntu 14.04 and other LTS platforms used in universities or similar places still use GHC 7.6.3, I would add `import Control.Applicative` to `<$>` (or use `map read \`fmap\` getArgs`).

Comment: I would not use OS packages at all - but I guess that's another discussion - but yes that could be a problem (not for the OP as it seems)